# Maven Skipping tests automatically

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testng

While running selenium tests through maven, it automatically skips one of my tests and run the other ones well. Not sure why bcos default behavior of maven is not to skip tests. Despite adding `<skipTests>false</skipTests>` , it still didn't resolve the problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite verbose="1" name="BudgetPlus">
<test name="seleniumTests">
       <classes>
        <class name="tests.reportMultipleTests" />
        <class name="tests.addProposalMaxValuesTest" />
        <class name="tests.addProposalMinValuesTest" />
        <class name="tests.addProposalValuesTest" />
        <class name="tests.addProposalValuesTest1" />
        <class name="tests.LoginTest" />
        <class name="tests.InvalidLoginTest" />
       </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

So in the above snippet, it always skips the first test "tests.reportMultipleTests" , if i remove the other remaining tests and just keep this one "tests.reportMultipleTests", it identifies and run the test successfully but if there are multiple tests then it skips it. After all the tests are ran, Skip count is also 0. This is weird problem and not sure how to resolve it. I also upgraded the version of maven, testng, did a clean install, deleted the .m2 repo and ran the build again but nothing worked. Has anyone encountered similar issue?

This is my Maven profile :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>BudgetPlus</groupId>
<artifactId>BudgetPlus</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/test/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <skipITs>false</skipITs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: First why are you changing the convention and defining the souceDirectory ? Which is not a good idea...Just put your test classes into `src/test/java` and follow the naming conventions...

Comment: tests are under src/test/java folder

Comment: Why are you defining `sourceDirectory` does not make sense...

Comment: your comments unfortunately do not help solve my problem

Comment: The comment not but your missing answer...The point is if you change conventions you should really know what you are doing...and it does not sounds like that...So I would suggest to remove that from your configuration and best put your project on Github or at least a sample project so we can take a look....

Comment: @avanishf - Can you try bumping up the verbosity level in your suite to  `verbose=3` and run again? You should see some information on why the test gets skipped when run together with other tests. My guess is that when your test combines with others, something like a config method fails and so your test gets skipped. On a side note, you seem to be configuring maven to look for source code under `src/test/java`, default is `src/main/java`. Only tests reside in `src/test/java`. Was that intentional ?

Comment: @khmarbaise i have commented the `<sourceDirectory>` as there is no src/main/java

Comment: @KrishnanMahadevan , i have set the verbose level to 3 and didn't find any more details in the logs. it was same as verbose 1. There is nothing in src/main/java, so i have commented it out. Regarding skipping it provides this info :  "skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\Avanish\BudgetPlus\src\main\resources"

Comment: ok got it. The test "test.reportMultipleTests" which was giving issue had multiple sub-tests with priority set to 1,2,3 etc.. while other test classes (tests.addProposalMaxValuesTest, tests.addProposalMinValuesTest) didn't had priority set. i removed the priority part and that solved!

Comment: @avanishf - Please add your observation as an answer to your question and then accept it as well, so that the question gets closed.

Answer (score 0):

I use maven using eclipse IDE for java . If you click right click on project and select run as ->choose configuration -> then you will find skip test check box . Check or uncheck as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

This is maven param **-DskipTests=true**

> mvn clean install -DskipTests=true;

Comment: You can leave out the '=true', `-DskipTests`is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The test "test.reportMultipleTests" which was giving issue had multiple sub-tests with priority set to 1,2,3 etc.. while other test classes (tests.addProposalMaxValuesTest, tests.addProposalMinValuesTest) didn't had priority set. i removed the priority part and that solved!